# I am not getting user photo

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am not getting user photo using url `$getUserphoto = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value';`

I am using REST API using cURL.

```
private static $scopes = array("openid",
                               "offline_access",
                               "mail.read",
                               "User.Read",
                               "User.Read.All",                                
                               "calendars.readwrite",
                               "contacts.readwrite");
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error its just blank response. even i escaped $ sign but no response. $getUserUrl = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/\$value'; if i use $getUserUrl = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo'; i get metadata response. photo is there and if i use microsoft explorer i get my photo.

Comment: Could you post some more of your code, so we can see what it is doing? Also, please provide the headers and any body from the photo $value response.

Comment: do you have sample code written in php which i can try here. if possible otherwise I will send you my code.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you aren't encoding the result appropriately:

```php
$imageData = RequestManager::sendGetRequest(
        Constants::RESOURCE_ID . '/v1.0/users/' . $user . '/photo/$value',
        array(
            'Authorization: Bearer ' . $_SESSION['access_token'],
        )
    );
    return base64_encode($imageData);
```

Then, in your HTML:

```
<img class="ms-Persona-image" src="data:image/*;base64,{{ avatar }}">
```

If neither of these work, please use a tool such as [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to see what response code you get back with the response.

Comment: Hi Caitlin I have still no luck in getting user image im <img > tag I am using PHP language. I am getting meta data of image but how to manipulate that data so that i can see image.

Comment: Can you please show me both the code which you use to make the request as well as the HTML you use to display the image?

Comment: Hello Caitlin 
I want solution like this blog but in PHP in this blog example is in angular.js I am using PHP language
https://blog.mastykarz.nl/office-365-groups-api/